# Jasmine testing, using a constructor in the beforeEach

Tags: jasmine

i am attempting to create a new instance of two classes that i have already written in separate files.  when i try to create new instances of them in the beforeEach() section of the test code, the tests return undefined for my newly created objects.  however when i create them in each IT section the test run perfectly.

```
describe("placeStone", function() {
beforeEach(function() {
    var go = new Display();
    var logic = new Internals(go);    
    logic.tempBoard = [ array];
});
it("should place a black stone at 0,6", function() {  
   logic.placeStone(logic.black,0,6);  
   expect(logic.tempBoard[6][0]).toEqual("B");
});
```

this returns logic undefined.

```
describe("placeStone", function() {

it("should place a black stone at 0,6", function() {  
   var go = new Display();
   var logic = new Internals(go);    
   logic.tempBoard = [ array];
   logic.placeStone(logic.black,0,6);  
   expect(logic.tempBoard[6][0]).toEqual("B");
});
});
```

this seems to work the way i want. how can i get it to work in the beforeEach() section?

Answer (score 3):

*var logic* should be defined in the scope of the describe function, then it exists both in the scope of the *beforeEach* function and the spec (the *it* function), e.g.

```
describe('suite', function () {
    var myVar;
    beforeEach(function(){
        myVar = 10;
    });
    it('checks myVar', function () {
        expect(myVar).toEqual(10);
    });
});
```